# Renaming a core data property within an NSManagedObject class

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode5

I want to rename a property, `sortOrder`:

[image]

to `sequence`, within an NSManagedObject class.
(example illustration only)

[image]

And have followed the steps of *Lightweight Migration*.

[image]

The challenge is that the Lightweight Migration doesn't actually affect the NSManagedObject class (`FormItems`).

So the code still uses the `sortOrder` property.  I can run a refactor-rename through XCode to change the code, but will that then break my backwards DB compatibility due to the renaming within the class?

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightweight migration should work as expected. This statement

> The challenge is that the Lightweight Migration doesn't actually affect the NSManagedObject class (FormItems).

is not necessarily true. It LW migration should affect all changed entities.

You can refactor your code to use the new name and

1. Create a new model version.
2. Make the changes to the property *after changing to* the new model version.
3. Make sure the persistent store has the right options.
   `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` and
   `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption`

Comment: Do I need to bother with the 'Renaming ID' then as well?

Comment: No, it should be - as it says - "automatic".

Answer (score 0):

1. As described by @Mundi, you need to create a new model version.
2. After that, you need to rename sortOrder as sequence in your code.
3. In mapping model, value expression for attribute "sequence" would be $source.sortOrder. This will retain all previous values after migration.

Comment: So what happened that my `sequence` attribute within .xcmappingmodel has a blank expression?  :/

Comment: For core data, it is not renaming of an attribute. It is creating a new attribute and deleting one old attribute. It will not map the data automatically between the two. If you keep value expression as blank, you will lose data which was in sort Order attribute.